# Is there a way to short-circuit a ternary operation?

Tags: c#, ternary-operator

I can write

```
if(Model.DecisionReason != null && Model.DecisionReason.Length > 35)
    return Model.DecisionReason.Substring(0, 32) + "...";
else
    return Model.DecisionReason;
```

and the `&&` comparison in the `if` will short-circuit, preventing an exception if `Model.DecisionReason` is null. However, if I write

```
return (Model.DecisionReason != null && Model.DecisionReason.Length > 35) ?
     Model.DecisionReason.Substring(0, 32) + "..." :
     Model.DecisionReason;
```

There is no short-circuit and I hit the exception. Is there a way to make it to short-circuit, or am I forced to either wrap the length comparison in an `if` check for the null or nest ternaries (not the most readable)?

Comment: Both samples work when I run them. I suspect your analysis is at fault - am I right in guessing that this is a cut-down sample of the problematic code to illustrate the problem? If so - look elsewhere - the ternary short circuits in exactly the same way as the if.

Comment: Wasn't really cut down, but written from scratch. Turns out I had the results swapped in the real code, so if it was null it short-circuited and tried to take the substring. Voted to close as too localized.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Both of the code samples you wrote will have identical behavior.  It's not the `if` that's short circuiting but simply a core component of the `&&` expression itself.

Comment: Actually, the `if` does also short-circuit in the sense that it doesn't evaluate either the `then` or the `else` branch, based on the actual result of the condition. ;-)

Comment: The boolean part of the ternary short curcuits the same as in the if, but unlike the if, the true and false conditions do not short circuit - both are executed.

Comment: @gburton Microsoft documentation suggests that's not the case? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/conditional-operator