# How to suppress ternary operator from evaluating the non-executed result

Tags: c#, .net

I'm having issues trying to set a bunch of Numeric form controls from a dictionary of values.  I want to be able to check if the corresponding key exists in the dictionary before attempting to set the Numeric control's value.

My problem is that the ternary operator evaluates both resulting expressions even if only one of them is going to be used.  This throws a "Key not found" exception from the Dictionary.

Is there an easy way to set a numeric form control to the value in a dictionary only if the corresponding key exists (and if not 0)?

(`Position` is an `enum` and `MyCoordinate` is a `struct` containing a list of axes)

```
Dictionary<Position, MyCoordinate> pos = DataManager.Instance.ToolChanger.GetPositionCoordinates();

pos1TNumeric.Value = pos.ContainsKey(Position.ElectrodePosition01) ? 0M : (decimal)pos[Position.ElectrodePosition01].Axes[EDMAxis.T];
pos2TNumeric.Value = pos.ContainsKey(Position.ElectrodePosition02) ? 0M : (decimal)pos[Position.ElectrodePosition02].Axes[EDMAxis.T];
pos3TNumeric.Value = pos.ContainsKey(Position.ElectrodePosition03) ? 0M : (decimal)pos[Position.ElectrodePosition03].Axes[EDMAxis.T];
pos4TNumeric.Value = pos.ContainsKey(Position.ElectrodePosition04) ? 0M : (decimal)pos[Position.ElectrodePosition04].Axes[EDMAxis.T];
pos5TNumeric.Value = pos.ContainsKey(Position.ElectrodePosition05) ? 0M : (decimal)pos[Position.ElectrodePosition05].Axes[EDMAxis.T];
```

My current solution is probably going to just make a wrapper function that is passed the dictionary key and returns the correct decimal value.  I'm wondering if there's an easier way.  Thanks!

Comment: `the ternary operator evaluates both resulting expressions even if only one of them is going to be used` That's false.   It does no such thing.  If that operand is being evaluated, then that's the path being taken.

Comment: Looks like i'm an idiot and forgot to invert my result.... Disregard this question...

Comment: @Servy you're totally correct, i forgot to invert my result

Comment: @EMUEVIL consider to use `TryGetValue` method to avoid searching in dictionary twice

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a way to short-circuit a ternary operation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10128110/is-there-a-way-to-short-circuit-a-ternary-operation)

Comment: @SergeyBerezovskiy thanks! i'll implement that.

Comment: I would write custom extension method anyway - all that repeating code is hard to read and error prone.

Comment: @IvanStoev I typically advocate against extension methods. It's just an extra library that you end up having to carry around with you, usually

Comment: @JoePhillips So you must hate Linq then.

Comment: @juharr Not at all. Because it's part of .net and not some random custom library you have to reference.

Comment: @JoePhillips Then I guess you hate MoreLinq then.

Comment: @juharr I don't use it so I wouldn't know. I think you are misunderstanding what I mean by "custom library" though. I'm referring to non-published libraries

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you have to switch your statements:

```
pos1TNumeric.Value = pos.ContainsKey(Position.ElectrodePosition01) ? (decimal)pos[Position.ElectrodePosition01].Axes[EDMAxis.T] : 0M;
```

So if the key exists, you take the value. Otherwise take your default value.

```
 var value = bool_expression ? if_true : if_false;
```

Comment: I wonder why downvoting correct answer